# Finding the diameter of a circle from the length and position of a chord

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I have a circle of unknown diameter. I do, however, know the length of a chord and the distance between the centre of the circle and the centre of the chord.

Please see picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhHv3.png) where I have added some sample values: I want to determine the value of *d*

**UPDATE:** Diagram illustrating maxmilgram's solution below [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHwqv.png)

The solution in summary is: because we know lines $MN$ and $NP$ an well as angle $∠PNM$ we can solve using simple trig!

Comment: In your diagram you know the length of the chord and the distance from center of chord to center of circle. Is that an equivalent description of the knowns?

Comment: @coffeemath - yes, it is - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets call the center point of the circle $M$, the two endpoints of the chord (="diamenter line") $P$ and $Q$ and the midpoint of the chord $N$.

Now observe that the distance between $M$ and $P$ is $r=d/2$, the distance between $N$ and $M$ is $h$ and the distance between $N$ and $P$ is $x/2$. Furthermore the angle $\angle PMN$ is $90°$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Also, note that EVERY chord is parallel to a diameter!

Comment: This is where I got to - a right-angle triangle where I know one side (h) and one (right) angle: but that isn't enough - as far as I understand - for trig to help...

Comment: You know the length of the other side as well, as described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, yes - my mistake. Could you explain how the line NP is x/2? It is obviously right, I just can't work out why! Thanks so much

Comment: The bisection of $PQ$ is by definition the set of all points with the same distance from $P$ and $Q$. Since $P$ and $Q$ are both points are on the circle they have the same distance from the center point. Thus the center point lies on the bisection. The bisection is orthogonal to the line and cuts the distance in half. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#Line_segment_bisector

Comment: I thought I understood, but I drew it out based on your description to test and I must have misunderstood because I end up with a calculated diameter *smaller* than the length of the parallel line! Can you see where I went wrong from this diagram? https://imgur.com/2KzmiSZ

Comment: $P$ and $Q$ are on the chord not on the diameter.

Comment: Ah, got it. I will post an updated diagram into the question. Thanks again!